# Manually set language for code-highlighting in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am managing my style declarations in a .cshtml file so I can dynamically code values, for example color-codes that I need to be repeat often. I'm using MVC's routing capabilities to serve up the stylesheet with a .css extension, so this is all opaque to the end-user.

The .cshtml file contains mostly CSS, of course, with only a few dozen values passed in dynamically, and some calls to helpers I've written to make the CSS easier to maintain, so I'd like to be able to view this file with CSS code-highlighting.

QUESTION:
Is is possible to set the language for syntax hightlighting manually for a given file with Visual Studio?

Note: I know this is easy with Notepad++, but I'd prefer to do everything with the same editor.

**UPDATE**: I'v realized this problem can (I think) be cooked down to "Where is the executable for the the *CSS Source Editor (default)* ?". This  is an option when choosing "Open With..." on a CSS file, but not an option when choosing "Open With..." on a .cshtml file, so if I could just navigate to its location using the "Add" button in that wizard, my problem is solved. But...where is that editor??!

**UPDATE (2)**: <strike>My hack works, but as it is ugly, I'd still like to know how to open in the default CSS editor.</strike>

**UPDATE (3)**: I could *really* use a solution here, and it seems a general solution would be beneficial in many circumstances. Hence the bounty.

**UPDATE (4)**: OK, My hack really *does* work -- you just have to open the file with the VS's HTML Editor instead of the Razor editor.

Comment: See my answer below, hopefully It might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my hack:

You *can* open a .cshtml file with Visual Studio's HTML editor, and that editor will recognize CSS if nested inside `<style>` tags. But since the `<style>` (or any) tag is invalid inside a .css file, and will cause styles to break, the way around this is to embed the open and closing  tags in razor or CSS comments:

```
/*<style>*/

[my style declarations]

/*</style>*/
```

OR:

```
@*<style>*@

[my style declarations]

@*</style>*@
```

Yuck. But it works.

**update** It *does* work -- just be careful to select VS's HTML editor and  **not**  the Razor editor when using "open with..."

Comment: Ugh. This is not working anymore. Somehow VS has "figured out" my dirty trick -- when I open the file, it shows the CSS syntax highlighting for a few seconds, then it disappears. I hadn't editted my stylesheet in a while, so not sure what upgrade/plugin/what-not triggered this.

Comment: It's the addition of any C# code block inside the `<style>` block that kills the CSS highlighting.

Comment: Using /* */ sets some ReSharper alarm-bells, try using:
// <style>
code here
// </style>

Thanks for the genius idea though, gonna make my life a bit easier using .cshtml as CSS/JS output

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it in Visual Studio 6:

[**Setting Syntax Coloring**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265717%28v=vs.60%29.aspx#_asug_to_set_syntax_coloring_for_a_custom_html_variation)

**To set syntax coloring for a custom HTML variation**

1. Create a text file with an extension of `.hlx` in the `\msdev\bin\ide` directory.
   The first line of the file is a signature that uniquely identifies the type of the file. It contains the name of the variation that will be displayed on the Source File Properties page. After the signature line, the format resembles that of a Windows initialization file. A semicolon at the beginning of a line indicates a comment.
2. Create three sections in the file: an `[Elements]` section, an `[Attributes]` section, and an `[Entities]` section.
   Each section contains a list of names separated by spaces, carriage returns, or line feeds. The names do not need to be in alphabetical order. You must specify all the elements, attributes, and entities you want to color. 

   See the example for a general outline of a [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265717%28v=vs.60%29.aspx#_asug_sample_hlx_file) `.hlx` file.
3. Save the `.hlx` file.

**Note:** If the custom variation you specify in the `.hlx` file has the same name as a built-in HTML support, it will override the built-in HTML support. There is a 14-character limit to the name of the HTML variation you specify.

Comment: This is for VS6 -- doesn't seem to apply to VS 2010. Sorry for not specifying that version.

Comment: That's what I discovered when I wrote my first update to the question. Unfortunately, VS does not present the CSS source editor in the list of options for opening up a cshtml file. If I could browse to that editor, then I could add it to the list of editors available for cshtml. But where the heck is that CSS source editor executable fiel???